# Convert range of formatted numbers to text strings (keeping formatting when pasting, but convert to text)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a large range of numbers with varying number formatting. I would like to change all numbers in the array, including their formatting, into text strings (so that formatting characters like '$' are stored as a string in each cell, not as an integer with formatting applied).

The goal is to be able to store these formatted strings so that I can later access them directly (i.e., using R or Python or mailmerge), while keeping all of the number formatting easily available.

In the image below you can see that the stored value is actually 1001 (as a numeric value).

[image]

I want a way to change arrays of values (i.e., C2, D2, and E2) to match the format shown in cell C4 below. In this format, all formatting characters are stored as a text string, **not** as number formatting. The equation bar correctly shows that the value is a text string "$1,001".

[image]

Pasting as value, or pasting as value with number formatting, **does not** produce the desired result. Using .text in VBA reads the cell value and the number formatting, but does not transform the numbers and formatting characters ("$1,001") into a string, as desired. Copying data into notepad, then copying back into excel does produce the desired result.

Is there a way in Excel (using VBA if necessary) to change arrays of formatted numbers to text strings, as described above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array of string of the `.Text` then format the range as text and paste the array back:

```
    Sub ttt()
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
        
        Dim t() As String
        ReDim t(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To rng.Columns.Count) As String
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(t, 1)
            Dim j As Long
            For j = 1 To UBound(t, 2)
                t(i, j) = rng.Cells(i, j).Text
            Next j
        Next i
        
        
        rng.NumberFormat = "@"
        rng = t
    End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: It's a shame that `.Text` doesn't return an array, otherwise this would be a lot easier.

Comment: Be sure that all cells are completely visible before you run that code - text returns *exaclty* what is displayed, and if a cell is too narrow and displays '####', you will get '####' and your data is gone.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you - this works *beautifully*

Comment: In addition to Scott's helpful approach, I posted a way out to @FunThomas ' caveat of truncated number displays.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick alternative to @ScottCraner 's helpful approach via XML spreadsheet**

Alerted by @FunThomas ' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73054635/convert-range-of-formatted-numbers-to-text-strings-keeping-formatting-when-past/73054782#comment129027684_73054782) that incompletely visible numeric values (shown e.g. as `####`)
also result in a truncated "####" string after conversion to `.Text`,
I demonstrate a simple way out via

> `Range.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)`, a.k.a. `Value(11)` property

- returning a wellformed **xml content string** including all necessary type & style indications and
- allowing a **quick type conversion** from numbers to strings
  (here by a simple replace action) **without**
  the *need to check for not fully displayed number values*.

```
Sub Num2Txt(src As Range, Optional tgt As Range)
    If IsMissing(tgt) Then Set tgt = src        ' overwrite target by default
'a) change number type in wellformed xml spreadsheet content, aka Value(11)
    Dim xml As String
    xml = Replace(src.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet), "=Number", "=String")
'b) write converted xml spreadsheet content to target
    tgt.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet) = xml ' same as: tgt.Value(11) = xml
End Sub
```

**Example call**

To overwrite the source range use `Num2Txt rng` with only *one* argument
overwriting the target range by default, passing a second argument allows
to define any target range.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Tabelle2.Range("A1:A10")  ' set (source) range
    Num2Txt rng, rng.Offset(, 2)        ' copy e.g. 2 columns to the right 
'   Num2Txt rng                         ' overwrite source range
```

**MS Help reference**

- [Range.Value property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)
- [XlRangeValueDataType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrangevaluedatatype)

Answer (score 0):

I have just made a simple formula to achieve $0,000.00 string instead of formatting.

Click this picture link: ["Concate" and "Text" Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpJSX.png)

Formula:

> **="$"&TEXT(E6,"0,000.00")**

Check out these 2 images,,,, to Explain this scenario:

Click this picture link:  [Formatting number as "$0,000.00" which obviously doesn't fulfill the purpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO3IR.png)

Click this picture link: [As you want, but this is formula, let's test it as shown in next image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkpbt.png)

Click this picture link: [The test succeeded: the result of formula when pasted as "Paste Value", you can see the result as "$0,000.00" string instead of format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zac5D.png)

try it and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Apologize, I am new to this site, and not authorize to paste direct screenshot here.